# Parsing body with pagination on Postman

Tags: javascript, json, api, postman

I have a Postman test script that downloads response body on a page and then moves on to the next page; it appends all data on all pages into a single environment variable called "responseData":

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var old = pm.environment.get("responseData");
old = JSON.parse(old);
// filter jsonData if needed


old.push(jsonData);
old = JSON.stringify(old);
pm.environment.set("responseData", old);

var page = parseInt(pm.environment.get("page"));
var pageSize = parseInt(pm.environment.get("take"));
var skip = parseInt(pm.environment.get("skip"));
skip = page * pageSize;
page = page + 1;
pm.environment.set("skip", skip);
pm.environment.set("page", page);
```

The script above works fine. However, I don't want to keep the whole response body, but only the fields called "Id". On each page there are hundreds of Ids as well as other fields:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "child": {
                "Id": "c4d611bf-c522",
                "Api": null,
                 ...
```

How should I update script in order to only keep the "Id"s?

Thank you!

Comment: 2-3 data objects in data array will provide some insights to provide some generic solutions. consider to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below script should add only the ids and only once. The pagination part is the same.

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var old = pm.environment.get("responseData");
old = JSON.parse(old);
var results = jsonData.data;
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
    if(!old.includes(results[i].child.id)){
    old.push(results[i].child.id);
    }
}

old = JSON.stringify(old);
pm.environment.set("responseData", old);

var page = parseInt(pm.environment.get("page"));
var pageSize = parseInt(pm.environment.get("take"));
var skip = parseInt(pm.environment.get("skip"));
skip = page * pageSize;
page = page + 1;
pm.environment.set("skip", skip);
pm.environment.set("page", page);
```